# couldn't load image in opencv(python)

Tags: 12.04, python, opencv, image-processing

I installed opencv & python in ubuntu12.04. I'm unable to load the image. I tried

```
$ from cv2.cv import *
```

which showed the error

```
"from: can't read /var/mail/cv2.cv"
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be typing the python `import` command directly in a terminal (bash shell) - you must enter into an interactive python shell first by typing `python` (the shell prompt should change from `$` to `>>>`)

```
$ python
>>> from cv2.cv import *
```

Alternatively, you can use a text editor to write a python script file.

Comment: well... after running the above commands it showed Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
>>>

Comment: did you actually install the python-opencv package? what version?

Comment: ive instaleed python 2.7

Comment: Python itself doesn't include the opencv modules - you need to install another package called 'python-opencv'. If you don't already have the opencv libraries it will automatically install those as well.

Comment: Ive installed open-cv and python separately. Wont it work?

Comment: Do I've to mount the download folder before running from cv2.cv import *?